# How do I search for a two character word using a MySQL query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm using MySQL FULLTEXT search (in Natural Language mode). Example:

```
SELECT Mem_id FROM Members WHERE MATCH (job_title) AGAINST ('".mysql_real_escape_string($keywordsWanted)."')
```

I noticed that searching for "**web** developer" or "**PHP** coder" didn't work too well and so I added `ft_min_word_len=3` to the MySQL config file (*/etc/mysql/my.cnf*). However, two character search terms are still an issue. e.g. "**IT** contractor", "**PR** manager", "**3D** design", etc. These are some strategies I was thinking of trying:

- Use `ft_min_word_len=2` - Won't this make the index MASSIVE and slow the DB down?
- Alter the query to use LIKE in cases where the keyword is less than 3 characters?
- Auto-translate common acronyms into full words. e.g. IT->"Information Technology"
- Change the UI so a Javascript popup warns the user that 2 character words aren't counted so they should rephrase the question
- Move to use Zend Lucene or another search technology

What do you advise / How have you tackled this problem?

Answer (score 3):

For reference, what I ended up doing was changing "`ft_min_word_len=2`" in the MySQL config file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf). Performance didn't seem to be noticeably worse. Using FTS over LIKE/REGEXP has the advantage of automatic results ranking and automatic plural matching.

By the way, I also had a problem with some of the MYSQL stopwords. In particular "it" and "us" (because they mean "Information Technology" and "United States" in my problem domain). You can find a list of stop words to use here: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/full-text-revealed.html#stopwords. I saved this list to a file called */etc/mysql/stopword_list.txt* and then added "`ft_stopword_file='/etc/mysql/stopword_file.txt'`" to the MySQL config file. Then I restarted MYSQL (`sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart`) and dropped and recreated my FTS index's.

Comment: It does not work with innodb full text search, i has to add `innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2` as well to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

How about searching with [mysql's pattern matching `LIKE`/`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

For example:

`SELECT * FROM Members WHERE job_title LIKE '".$job_title[0]."%';`

Or you can use regular expressions:

`SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name REGEXP '^.....$';`

You can also store the job title in a separate field or table.

Comment: REGEXPs like `something$` require table full scans

Comment: @ElvisCiotti this is a 3 year old question, i am sorry for my lack of understanding back then.

Comment: 3y old but the question is still valid :)